# Rails 3 - Negative Captcha with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, captcha, spam-prevention

I discovered that there is a lot of spam registrations into one of my Rails apps, so I have to make some spam protection. I don't wanna use captcha as I think it's frustrating for real people. I like the idea of **Negative Captcha**. There is a ruby gem for it - https://github.com/subwindow/negative-captcha.

Does anybody **how to implement Negative Captcha with Devise**? I want to use it for sing up form.

I can't get to Devise controller, so it's not possible to follow the instructions.

Or if you have an idea how to implement some kind of "negative captcha" without this gem, it would be really helpful.

Thank you in advance! I appreciate your help.

Petr

Comment: You can "get" to Devise controller. Just follow [Devise's readme instructions](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers).

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty, but seems that is working. Any suggestions welcome.

https://gist.github.com/jtsagata/d1eac59bdf8f975a6a9d